# Rearrange product collection in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, product-list

In product listing page I need to rearrange product listing price.

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSort('price', 'ASC')
            ->load();
```

I tried above code in list.phtml page it's working in initial list.

Not working in ajax scroll

Comment: Well, I'm guessing your ajax call calls a controller, did you change it in your controller too?

Comment: You want add price filter ??

Comment: @Arunendra yes i need price sorting

Comment: @JulienLachal I don't know where i need to change controller

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `_getProductCollection()` function.

Or copy `List.php` from core location

> app/code/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/

And paste in local codePool

> app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php

And add your new filter just before this line

```
$this->prepareSortableFieldsByCategory($layer->getCurrentCategory());
```

your code will be like:

```
$this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection()->addFieldToFilter('price','ASC');
```